# Another word for a wine glass made of glass

Tags: single-word-requests

Checking [here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/types-of-cup-or-glass), it shows that I can use "goblet" but goblet is very medieval sounding and conjures images as if it is made of metal or gold and studded with diamonds. I am looking for a word which is to be used in the modern context.

Update- The reason I'm averse to using "wine glass" is because it would be used to contain something other than wine and using the term would just conjure a wrong image.

Comment: There are similar words, but I don't think there's an exact synonym of "wine glass".. unless the glass is used for something else (ex: a flute is used for drinking champagne).

Comment: What is wrong with _wine glass_? It describes exactly what you describe. Can you describe in more detail what you are looking for, and why _wine glass_ is not right?

Comment: FIFY: http://winefolly.com/tutorial/types-of-wine-glasses/  You'll want to include your own research in your questions.  I'm pretty sure I found this with half the keyboard tied behind my back. :-)

Comment: @oerkelens: I'm trying to use the vessel for containing something other than wine and using wine glass might be misleading so I'm trying to avoid it. Some words are associated with certain contents like tankard, tumbler or flute glass.

Comment: Even if it contains something else, if you want to describe the specific shape (and material) of a wine glass, _wine glass_ will cause the least confusion. A tumbler should never contain wine, a flute only certain wines, and archaic words like goblet will make people stop to think about its shape. When you mention a goblet I would probably not assume it's made of glass. If I drink water from a long-drink glass, I think the image is clear, and nobody will assume the water is a screwdriver just because I mention the long-drink glass.

Comment: @KristinaLopez: I have. It is literally the second word in the question, linking to the site. Also, I have seen the page you have mentioned but it did not seem relevant as it merely names what drink should be served in which shape of glass...not alternate names of the glass (except the first row which is covered in my link)...

Comment: You didn't say that in your question!

Comment: @BillJ: Say what ? I'll amend the question to reflect it...

Comment: That it was for containing something other than wine.

Comment: Gotcha.  If it's a glass wine glass that will be used for something other than wine, more generic terms such as "stemmed glass" or "snifter" are fairly evocative for most people, I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the world of restaurants the collective noun for all the different shapes and sizes of wine glasses is stemware. "Goblets" do conjure up a picture of metal vessels but these are not best suited to enjoying wine. Curiously, a type of glass popular in the world of restaurants in the UK and US in the 1950's and 60's was a Paris Goblet, the terminology denoting its spherical shape (with aperture). This was a stemmed glass the shape of a tennis ball (perhaps a little smaller) and used mainly for all kinds of red wine. The Paris Goblet has all but disappeared and been replaced at the high end by a bewildering array of shapes and sizes to "suit" particular wines, wine regions and grape varieties. In the UK in the 1950's and 60's a schooner was the glass of choice for Sherry. Ditto a coupe for Champagne now thankfully replaced by a flute.

Comment: This is a great start on an answer. Questions should be answered as an expert would answer them: comprehensively, with explanation and context. You've provided much good information. Could you please demonstrate that your answer is right, ideally with citations.

Comment: The Paris goblet is alive and well in the UK remaining common, if not at the cutting edge of cool.